# CSS slideshow (varying slide times)

Tags: css, slideshow

I can't seem to be able to make a fully working CSS slideshow where the time the slides are shown for varies. Do I need to use multiple keyframes or is there another way to do it? If yes, an explanation would be much appreciated :^)

Comment: do you want it to be in css with no javascript?

Comment: Yeah, I would like it to be pure CSS/Html if possible

Comment: This should be possible using a single CSS animate with keyframes and an infinite loop, I'll see if I can put something together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single keyframe settup and CSS3's animate property.

To set the length each image is displayed, move the percentage start points around (total length is changed with `animation-duration`)

(Also, since I'm not preloading the images and the stock pictures I grabbed for an example are quite large, the first time through may be a little jumpy.)

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: slideshow;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
    0% { 
      /* Image 1 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/98046/pexels-photo-98046.jpeg");
    }
    26% { 
      /* Image 1 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/98046/pexels-photo-98046.jpeg");
    }
    30% {
      /* Image 2 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/98050/pexels-photo-98050.jpeg");
    }
    56% {
      /* Image 2 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/98050/pexels-photo-98050.jpeg");
    }
    60% { 
      /* Image 3 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/97909/pexels-photo-97909.jpeg");
    }
    96% { 
      /* Image 3 */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/97909/pexels-photo-97909.jpeg");
    }
    100% { 
      /* Image 1 (For a smooth transition back to the start) */
      background-image:url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/98046/pexels-photo-98046.jpeg");
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```

(I've left out browser prefixed properties in the example to keep it simple, in production you will probably want to include the prefixes: `-webkit-`, `-moz-` ect ect)